# in node.js, how to forward all events of module to another

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I am creating my own module, which sits on top of the 'net' module. My module has its own events, but also allows clients to listen on network events emitted by the tcp connection:

```
mymod.on('myevent',...); // my event
mymod.on('connect',...); // net event
mymod.on('end',...);     // net event
```

Right now I'm doing the following

```
...
tcp.on('connect',function(){ self.emit('connect');});
tcp.on('end',function(){ self.emit('end');});
...
```

Is there a more idiomatic way from me to simply forward all events (or a subset of events) from one module to clients of another module?

I expect such a scenario comes up all the time, so I'd like to do it the cleanest way I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've done in the past is [handle the `newListener` event](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_event_newlistener).  I don't bother attaching handlers until one is attached to my class.  Then, when it is, I attach it to the base class.

```
this.on('newListener', function (event, listener) {
    baseClassInstance.on(event, listener);
})
```

You can filter which events are passed through by checking the `event` parameter first.

Beware if you have to remove listeners.  This may not be the best solution in those cases.

Comment: It looks like it will be an 'removeListener' event in v0.10 (https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/3806)

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it and cannot test this at the moment but you could try the following;

Proxy all events to another object

```
tcp.emit = mymod.emit.bind(mymod);
```

Proxy events and call its own;

```
var oldEmit = tcp.emit;

tcp.emit = function() { 
    mymod.emit.apply(mymod, arguments); 
    return oldEmit.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Let me know if it works! The above is just a proof of concept and I have put no thought into the side effects of doing this.

Comment: This would mean that other modules listening to the events `tcp` would normally emit would not have their handlers called.

Comment: correct if it also needs to be available to other handlers, I have updated the code. Either way this is by no means a suggested usage just a proof of concept